# Java: Splitting a string at set length

Tags: java, string, split

I know that if I have a String with something like Apples,oranges I can split it by saying I want to split wherever theres a comma. But what if I want to split a set part of a string into several strings? More specifically, lets say I have a String with a date input such as "28062013", how can I split this into three strings so I have 28 in one string, 06 in one and 2013 in the last one? In other words, I want to split ddMMyyyy into three seperate strings of dd, MM and yyyy.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html I suspect if you read the Javadoc you might find something appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method of `String`. For instance:

```
String input = "28062013";
String date = input.substring(0, 2);  // "28"
String month = input.substring(2, 4); // "06"
String year = input.substring(4);     // "2013" - one-arg version goes to the end
```

Answer (score 0):

`String`'s `substring()` method is handy if you know the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring,if you have a constant format of the string.

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
String date = "28062013";
String day = date.substring(0,2);
String month = date.substring(2,4);
String year = date.substring(4,8);
```